# Internal Server Error with mod_rewrite and RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite for two things on my website.

Firstly, I want to hide .php file extensions in the URL..
(E.g. ***website.com/about.php*** is ***website.com/about***)
And I have this much working correctly.

But I also want to simplify URLs with queries and arguments to make them more SEO friendly.
(E.g. ***website.com/work/item.php?id=item-slug*** becomes ***website.com/work/item-slug***)

This is my .htaccess file so far, but its giving me an Internal Server Error...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

  # Interpret "work/(ARG)" as "work/item.php?id=(ARG)"
  RewriteRule ^work/(*.)$ work/item.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to convert "website.com/work/item.php?id=item-slug" to "website.com/work/item-slug"? I guess, you want "website.com/work/item/item-slug".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting 500 error because `*.` is an invalid regex that cannot be compiled. Moreover you need to skip files/directories from your last rewrite rule.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Interpret "work/(ARG)" as "work/item.php?id=(ARG)"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^work/([\w-]+)/?$ work/item.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked flawlessly :)